# WAMP missing localhost in URL

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

Hoping to catch the attention of user RiggsFolly (or any knowledgeable person) as I am having issues getting the virtual hosts list to appear as described here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 testing

::1 localhost
::1 testing
```

My http-vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/testing"
     ServerName testing
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/testing">
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have uncommented the "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" line in the http.conf file. I stopped and restarted the dnscache, and restarted and refreshed the wamp service several times. I have added the ';WAMPVHOSTSUBMENU' line in the right place in the wampmanager.tpl file.

Basically I followed the guide to the letter and the list of vhosts just won't appear. I know that I am not alone in this issue, I can see others with it out there but I cannot find a solution.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if SO is the right forum for a question like this.

Comment: Current version of that document is http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685 Alternatively post on the wampserver forum. Can you run http://testing and does it load your vhost